# How can I make my smiley (made with Windows Forms) relative, meaning that giving it a different (x,y) coordinate, it'll stay the same?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have made a smiley in the method 'tekenScherm' (=drawScreen), with given x, y, w (=width) and h (=height) variables. The base value of these variables are (100, 50, 300, 300). If you type in these values in my code you'll get a smiley.

Now, I want to be able to adjust these x, y, w and h values, so that the smiley stays relatively the same.

I've found out how to do this for the x and y coordinates already, so when you change the x coordinate for example, the left eye will change with x + 50, the right eye with x + 170, so it stays relatively the same.

Now, the problem is the width and the height of the eyes and mouth. I want to be able to change the width and height variable ('w', 'h'), and have the smiley stay relatively the same. I've tried all kinds of things, puzzling for hours, but I can't seem to make it work.

This is the code:

```
namespace Smiley2
{
    class HalloForm : Form
    {
        public HalloForm()
        {
            this.Text = "Smiley";
            this.BackColor = Color.White;
            this.Size = new Size(500, 500);
            this.Paint += this.tekenScherm;
        }

        void tekenScherm(object obj, PaintEventArgs pea)
        {
            float x, y, w, h, wOogLinks, wOogRechts;
            x = 100; y = 50; w = 300; h = 300;

            Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
            pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, x, y, w, h);
            pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, w, h);

            pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, x + 50, y + 50, 75 * (w / 300), 75 / 300f * h);
            pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, x + 170, y + 50, 75 * (w / 300), 75 / 300f * h);
            pea.Graphics.DrawArc(pen, x + 90, y + 135, 125f / 300 * w, 100f / 300 * h, 0, 180);
        }
    }

    class HalloWin3
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            HalloForm scherm;
            scherm = new HalloForm();
            Application.Run(scherm);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Graphics.ScaleTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.scaletransform?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Thanks, I'll consider that, but I want it if possible to be done through some expressions in the FillEllipse and DrawArc methods.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by calculating Width & Height Scales and then multiplying those values against each associated value. X & Y still give your offset and now you can change w & h as you like and the values will scale independently.

```
    void tekenScherm(object obj, PaintEventArgs pea)
    {
        float x, y, w, h, wOogLinks, wOogRechts;
        x = 100; y = 50; w = 300; h = 300;
        float scaleW = w / 300f;
        float scaleH = h / 300f;

        Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);
        pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Yellow, x, y, w, h);
        pea.Graphics.DrawEllipse(pen, x, y, w, h);

        pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(
            Brushes.White, 
            x + 50 * scaleW, 
            y + 50 * scaleH, 
            75 * scaleW, 
            75 * scaleH);
        pea.Graphics.FillEllipse(
            Brushes.White, 
            x + 170 * scaleW, 
            y + 50 * scaleH, 
            75 * scaleW, 
            75 * scaleH);
        pea.Graphics.DrawArc(
            pen, 
            x + 90 * scaleW, 
            y + 135 * scaleH, 
            125f * scaleW, 
            100f * scaleH, 
            0, 
            180);
    }
```